# how to display the contents from the status column as a heading in database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

Find the below data from Mysql Database and from this data when I count the status by using mobile number, I need the "status" to be displayed as heading of the row and the "count" should be displayed below the status.

```
**cust_mob_no       status**

918072740683    unattended
918072740683    closed
918072740683    NotApplicable
918072740683    Assigned
918072740683    NotApplicable
918072740683    open
918072740683    open
```

How to display the data as given below?

```
unattended  closed  NotApplicable   Assigned    open
   1          1           2           1           2
```

Comment: Use a case expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use select case like this

```
SELECT
    mobileNumber,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN (statusName='unattended') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unattended,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (statusName='closed' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (statusName='NotApplicable') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotApplicable,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (statusName='Assigned') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Assigned
FROM 
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    mobileNumber
```

[**DBFiddle Sample Code**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb8a8/1)

You can make use of pivot. sample query

```
SELECT [unattended], [closed],[NotApplicable],[Assigned],[open] FROM   
(SELECT [mobileNumber],[status] FROM MyTable )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT([mobileNumber]) FOR status IN ([unattended], [closed],[NotApplicable], 
[Assigned],[open])) AS Tab2
```

[**DB Fiddle Sample Code**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc1eb/7)

Comment: rdbms is mysql not ms sql server @diptee check tag

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
    SELECT
        cust_mob_no,  
        SUM(CASE WHEN (Status='unattended') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unattended,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (Status='closed' AND pagecount=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (Status='NotApplicable' AND pagecount=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotApplicable,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (Status='Assigned' AND pagecount=3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Assigned
    FROM 
        your_table
    GROUP BY 
        cust_mob_no
```